# "CPU does not support SVM" shown in Android-Studio on Windows, but not on Linux

Tags: android, linux, windows

I recently set up Android Studio on my computer (Lenovo E535, AMD Processor) on both Windows 7 and Arch Linux.

I got the emulator to run quite fast in Arch Linux and on Linux, I don't get the warning "Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM)".

Windows still shows me the warning. Virtulization is definitely enabled in the BIOS and it is definitely possible on my machine. Does Windows block SVM or does it not find it? Is it my Android Studio installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I found out for the next person who comes across this error:

Android Studio emulator won't run on Windows with an AMD processor. The error message is kind of misleading, as it suggests the problem is with the CPU. But it is within the troubleshoot message: "Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor".

Solutions could be installing Linux and running Android Studio on that (which might come with its own issues), using a physical device for testing or using the slow ARM images.

Comment: An update -- since mid-2018, this is supposed to no longer be true: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to @MelanieB.'s answer you can also alternatively download an external emulator and use that for testing.

For example this one: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/